# How to post tweets to multiple users accounts in laravel?

Tags: php, api, laravel, twitter

Im using this package https://github.com/thujohn/twitter to authorize users. I am able to authorize multiple users and get their data from twitter. I am struggling to post tweets to multiple users twitter accounts. Everytime I try to post it will only tweet to 1 users account. How can I post to multiple users accounts after authorization?

Here is the code I have tried. I save the user's tokens in the database and then grab it and put it in the session. :

```
Route::get('tweet', function(){
        $token = Input::get( 'oauth_token' );
        $verify = Input::get( 'oauth_verifier' );
        $screen_name = DB::table('profiles')->where('oauth_token', $token)->pluck('screen_name');
        $tweet_text = Input::get('tweet_text');

        Session::put('oauth_request_token', $token);
        Session::put('oauth_request_token_secret', $verify);
        Session::get('oauth_request_token');
        Session::get('oauth_request_token_secret');


        dd( Twitter::postTweet(['status' => $tweet_text, 'format' => 'json']) );

});
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you iterating the user and do auth, tweet, and logout for a single iteration? I think, it's cleaner, isn't it?

Comment: Do an iteration dude, iterate over your users list and post individually..

Comment: The reason I don't want to log the user out is because I want to add functionality where the user is able to schedule tweets to post at a later time. If I log them out then they would have to reauthorize before the app can post a scheduled tweet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong incase anyone else runs into this problem. You have two pairs of tokens. The package I used calls them both oauth_token and oauth_token_secret but in two different arrays. I used the wrong pair and so It would only post to the last authenticated account. Make sure you use access_token pair and store them for later use. Which you can then use to post to the right/multiple accounts.